# Registering a Composite Control

Tags: asp.net

I am learning custom controls and just finished my first one. The problem is that I am struggling to register it in my web config and have the compiler recognize it. Right now this results in a YSOD about the reference to the control.

note: exact error - Error Unknown server tag 'cc:LblTextBox'.

Thank you!

Web Config

```
//..
//..
     <pages>
       <controls>
         <add tagPrefix="cc" namespace="Controls.Server"/>
       </controls>
     </pages>
</system.web>
```

The control code-behind

```
namespace Controls.Server
{
    public class LblTextBox : CompositeControl
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

mark-up

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ControlsMain.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_ControlsMain" Trace="true" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
     <title>Controls Area</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
          First attempt at a simple composite control <br />
         <cc:LblTextBox ID="ccLblTbHybrid" runat="server" LabelText="Name:" />
   </div>
   </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stemmed from setting up the project as an ASP.Net Web Site

This has a drawback because the name of your assembly is not known till runtime.

I recreated the project as a ASP.Net Web Application, allowing for procompilation of the DLLs .... thus giving me the ability to give the project a namespace.

I then added abe's suggestion into the entry and all is working now

```
<add tagPrefix="cc" namespace="Controls.Server" assembly="DevLore"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try registering your composite control at the top of the page:

```
<%@ Register cc="myControls" Namespace="Controls.Server" %>
```

You might also try specifying the assembly in your web.config:

```
<add tagPrefix="cc" namespace="Controls.Server" assembly="whatever"/>
```

Comment: The assembly raises another issue. I noticed than when I created new folders and placed code into them, they did not auto generate the namespaces. I had to manually assign one. Normally I have never had to do that. Is it possible that I don't have an assembly name and that is why it cannot reference the namespace within the assembly? Just tossing ideas

Comment: another note, the project is a ASP.net Web Site project. As I understand, the assembly dlls are not precompiled ... will this affect how I register the namespace?

Comment: Your answer was partially correct! I posted my full solution.